# Disqus won’t load in any browser on my Jekyll website

Tags: jekyll, disqus

I am working on GitHub Pages with Jekyll. The Disqus code is located in `_includes/disqus.html` and has the following code:

```
<div class="comment">
<button class="show-comments"><i class="fa fa-comments" aria-hidden="true"> Load/Add comments</i></button>
<div id="disqus_thread"></div>
</div>
<script src={{ "/js/jquery.min.js" | prepend: site.baseurl }}></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.show-comments').on('click', function(){
          var disqus_shortname = '{{site.disqus-shortname}}'; 
          $.ajax({
                  type: "GET",
                  url: "http://" + disqus_shortname + ".disqus.com/embed.js",
                  dataType: "script",
                  cache: true
          });
          $(this).fadeOut();
    });
});
</script>
```

In the layouts folder I have a `blue.html` file with the following code for Disqus:

```
   {% include disqus.html %}
        {% else %}
        {% endif %}
```

And in the `config.yml` I noted my Disqus short name:

```
#comments disqus-shortname: eudemonis
```

But nothing of Disqus is loaded when clicking on the load comment section, [see test post.](https://eudemonis.github.io/blog/test//)

With or without the YAML front matter set as `comments: true` it doesn't work in neither Safari nor Chrome. I'm seriously at a loss.

I already tried a complete new file following Disqus documents with the Universal code but it doesn't work. Changing the Liquid tags manually with my Disqus short name also doesn't work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the problem is that your website is hosted with HTTPS but you are linking to Disqus with HTTP protocol in your `_includes/disqus.html`:

```
$.ajax({
  type: "GET",
  url: "http://" + disqus_shortname + ".disqus.com/embed.js",
  dataType: "script",
  cache: true
});
```

Error from Chrome console (hit F12 and see):

> Mixed Content: The page at 'https://eudemonis.github.io/blog/test//' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure script 'http://eudemonis.disqus.com/embed.js'. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.

To solve this, change the protocol to HTTPS:

```
url: "https://" + disqus_shortname + ".disqus.com/embed.js",
```

Or leave the protocol out and let the browser decide:

```
url: "//" + disqus_shortname + ".disqus.com/embed.js",
```

Comment: I know I should avoid thanks comments, but Thank You! This worked instantly and without a fuss